# How can I create a screenshot of a http website and save it on my server?

Tags: c#, windows, gd

How can I create a screenshot of an http website and save it on my server, using dot.net

```
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( resp.BodyStr );
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray ); 

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        stream.Close();
```

I have tried the above code but it's not working

Comment: You need to provide more detailed information. What exactly are you trying to do? Where are you getting stuck, and why?

Comment: Do you want to re-generate the image, or do you want to load the image from a different site?

Comment: If I completely misunderstood you, then 1. sorry, 2. edit it 3. explain it more.

Comment: @Itay Moav: The intention was noble, but from what I can tell, your edit does seem to completely change the nature of the question…

Comment: @htw: I actually think I marked straight on target :-)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Someone (not the author) **completely** changed the question in the OP. My answer was right for *that* question, and now I'm getting marked down for it.

- Use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to download the image from the web
- Construct a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) for the data
- Use the [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) method to load the stream into an image for your forms

Edit: Here is a wonderful answer for you. Check the accepted answer for *exactly* what you're after: [Using WebClient to get Remote Images Produces Grainy GIFs and Can't Handle PNG+BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499210/using-webclient-to-get-remote-images-produces-grainy-gifs-and-cant-handle-pngbm)