# Streaming pdf to the browser

Tags: .net

I have to read pdf from a vendor url and then stream to the webpage. I am trying following code but it doesn't work. I checkecked image bytes - those are populated.

This is how the image control's property set ImageUrl = "~/Controls/CheckImage/DraftImage.ashx?FB=F"

Following is the code from ashx page

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

```
 WebClient imageWebClient = new WebClient();
  CheckImg.Draft.FrontImage.Image = imageWebClient.DownloadData(Url);
  context.Response.Clear();
  context.Response.ContentType = ("application/pdf");
  context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=image.pdf");
  context.Response.BinaryWrite(CheckImg.Draft.FrontImage.Image); 
  context.Response.Flush();
  context.Response.Close();
  // context.Response.End(); 
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: What's "context", and where is it set?

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: Jeremy McGee:  I have updated my post with more details. Coding Gorilla: It does not show anything on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of trouble with this.  I final hit the right combo with this.
The data byte array is an abcPdf.net pdf doc.

hope this helps:

```
byte[] data = doc.GetData();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();    
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyPDF.PDF");
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", data.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(data);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
            Response.End();
```

Comment: Sorry it did not work.  Have you verified with the vendor that the format of their pdf is correct?  Also here's a suggestion to place the content in a memoryStream:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499210/using-webclient-to-get-remote-images-produces-grainy-gifs-and-cant-handle-pngbm

Comment: Everything works fine if I directly use on aspx file, so there is no issue with pdf or code but the same code when I use in Ashx page doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try to send some real simple content with your ashx page?  just to make sure you invoked all that you need for the ashx to work/

Comment: I tried simple ashx page like   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        }  works fine if I directly navigate to this ashx file but on aspx page I add image control and set imageurl to this ashx page. I don't see "Hellow word" on image control